# exception of order statistics

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

Assume $X_1,X_2,\dots ,X_n 
\overset{i.i.d}{\sim} F(.)
$

I define $X_{(1)},X_{(2)},\dots,X_{(n)}
$
Like that:
$X_{(1)}\leq X_{(2)}\leq \dots\leq X_{(n)}$

For $r\in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ :

What is the formula of $E[X_{(r)}]$?

I know the distribution function of $X_{(r)}$

$F_r(x)=\sum_{i=r}^{n}\binom{n}{i}
(F(x))^i(1-F(x))^{n-i}
$

But I still don't know what should I do

*i.i.d: independence identical distribution
$F_r(x)$: distribution function of $X_{(r)}$*

Comment: You seem to be aiming for something general.  Assuming the integrals are finite, you could say $E[X_{(r)}]= \int\limits_0^\infty \big(1-F_{(r)}(x)\big)\, dx  -\int\limits_{-\infty}^0 F_{(r)}(x)\, dx$

Comment: Yes I forget it,than you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For continuous independence random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n \sim F(.)$ we can find $f_r(x)$ (density function of $X_{(r)}$):

$f_r(x)=\frac{1}{B(r,n-r+1)}[F(x)]^{r-1}[1-F(x)]^{n-r}f(x)$

Then we can write expectation like that:
$E[X_{(r)}]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xf_r(x) dx$

For discontinuous random variable:

Assume $S^*_X=\{ x:f(x)>0\}$

We can write the $E[X_{(r)}]$ like that:

$E[X_{(r)}]=\sum_{x\in S^*_X}P(X_{(r)}\geq x)
=\sum_{x\in S^*_X}1-F_r(x)$

*B: Beta function*